# AWS Config Grantee for S3 Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to find the solution for config s3-bucket-policy-grantee-check-conformance-pack showing noncompliance on this S3 Bucket Policy and can't seem to find a solution.

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you describe more what you want to do, what have you done so far and what is your issue?

Comment: Are you referring to [s3-bucket-policy-grantee-check - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy-grantee-check.html)?

Comment: I have made sure that the policies only refer to AWS services as stated in the config explanation.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy-grantee-check.html

Comment: Some one another question said the solved this, but their explanation lacked enough information for me to solve this.